# Modifying Calculator to accept negative numbers

Tags: java, math, calculator

My current calculator can compute basic operators with respect to orders of operations (*, -, /, +) but doesn't accept negative numbers. However, it does work with (-2 * 2) and returns -4 as expected but doesn't work if the first number is not negative (2 * -2 returns 4). I have tried turning the "-" operator to make the 2nd operand negative (so it's just all addition and no subtraction if that makes sense) but I couldn't get it to work. Thank you for your time.

Here's my current code:

```
java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a math expression: ");
        String expression = scanner.nextLine();

        double result = 0;
        double currentNumber = 0;
        double multiplier = 1;
        boolean isNewNumber = true;
        boolean hasDecimal = false;
        double decimalMultiplier = 0.1;

        for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
            String currentSymbol = expression.substring(i, i + 1);

            if ("0123456789".indexOf(currentSymbol) != -1) {
                if (hasDecimal) {
                    currentNumber = currentNumber + Double.parseDouble(currentSymbol) * decimalMultiplier;
                    decimalMultiplier /= 10;
                } else {
                    currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + Double.parseDouble(currentSymbol);
                    isNewNumber = true;
                }
            } else if (currentSymbol.equals(".")) {
                hasDecimal = true;\
            } else if ("+-*/".indexOf(currentSymbol) != -1) {
                if (isNewNumber) {
                    if (currentSymbol.equals("+")) {
                        result = result + currentNumber * multiplier;
                    } else if (currentSymbol.equals("-")) {
                        if (i == 0 || "+-*/".indexOf(expression.substring(i - 1, i)) != -1) {
                            multiplier = -1;
                        } else {
                            result = result + currentNumber * multiplier;
                            multiplier = -1;
                        }
                    } else if (currentSymbol.equals("*")) {
                        multiplier = multiplier * currentNumber;
                    } else if (currentSymbol.equals("/")) {
                            multiplier = multiplier / currentNumber;
                    }
                    currentNumber = 0;
                    isNewNumber = false;
                    hasDecimal = false;
                    decimalMultiplier = 0.1;
                }
            }
        }

        result = result + currentNumber * multiplier;
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: On most real calculators, entering `2*-2`, pressing `-` results in the cancellation of `*`, so the result is `2*2`. When the `=` is pressed, `4` is calculated. Does your calculator work like that?  Makers of calculators solved the problem by creating a `-/+` (or `+/-`) key -- That is, a key that changes the sign of the number in the display.

Comment: One of my calculators had two `-` keys: The regular one was the subtraction operator. The other one, marked (-), was used to enter a negative sign when entering a negative number.

Comment: You might find it easier to write a state table to process inputs.  In this situation, If in operator state, see if unary operator follows and process accordingly.  There are many articles regarding state tables on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much required to get this to work, just 7 lines of code.

All I did was add a check for `-` right after another operator was found. Since the `isNewNumber` boolean was cleared after performing a mathematical operation, there was a gap to check if `-` came up again when the program was expecting a number.

The complete code with changes to make the expression `2*-2` get result `-4.0`

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a math expression: ");
        String expression = scanner.nextLine();

        double result = 0;
        double currentNumber = 0;
        double multiplier = 1;
        boolean isNewNumber = true;
        boolean hasDecimal = false;
        double decimalMultiplier = 0.1;
        boolean negNumber = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
            String currentSymbol = expression.substring(i, i + 1);

            if ("0123456789".indexOf(currentSymbol) != -1) {
                if (hasDecimal) {
                    currentNumber = currentNumber + Double.parseDouble(currentSymbol) * decimalMultiplier;
                    decimalMultiplier /= 10;
                } else { // apply neg
                    double doubleSymbol = Double.parseDouble(currentSymbol);
                    if (negNumber) {
                       doubleSymbol = doubleSymbol * -1;
                    }
                    currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + doubleSymbol;
                    isNewNumber = true;
                }
            } else if (currentSymbol.equals(".")) {
                hasDecimal = true;
            } else if ("+-*/".indexOf(currentSymbol) != -1) {
                if (isNewNumber) {
                    if (currentSymbol.equals("+")) {
                        result = result + currentNumber * multiplier;
                    } else if (currentSymbol.equals("-")) {
                        if (i == 0 || "+-*/".indexOf(expression.substring(i - 1, i)) != -1) {
                            multiplier = -1;
                        } else {
                            result = result + currentNumber * multiplier;
                            multiplier = -1;
                        }
                    } else if (currentSymbol.equals("*")) {
                        multiplier = multiplier * currentNumber;
                    } else if (currentSymbol.equals("/")) {
                        multiplier = multiplier / currentNumber;
                    }
                    currentNumber = 0;
                    isNewNumber = false;
                    hasDecimal = false;
                    decimalMultiplier = 0.1;
                    negNumber = false;
                } else {
                    negNumber = true;
                }
            }
        }

        result = result + currentNumber * multiplier;
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Annotation: Oddly enough, I have access to a library that does this type of operation: convert strings into expressions and run the calculation. It was hard not to post this here and explain how to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works with negative numbers now, but for division, for some reason I think it may be doing it backwards, where if I put 4 / 2, I get 0.5 and if I do 2 / 4, I get 2. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Also for some reason, it evaluates -2 + 2 as -4, and orders of operations work if multiplication/division is the last operator (ie. 2 + 2 * 4 evaluates to 10) but 2*4 + 2 evaluates to 12.

Comment: Can't really rob you of the fun of working it out. You'll find it will be similar to what I have provided: you need to keep track of the last operator and apply it appropriately.
Someone suggested in a comment on using a state table(?), I found the library used regex and split up the expression. A suggestion would be splitting the expression into variables then processing them through the order.